# Plot paraview data format file in mayavi

Tags: plot, jupyter-notebook, mayavi

I am solving PDE numerically using FEniCS with its python interface. I am using the ipython notebook to code in python and I want to plot the result using mayavi. I don't want to use paraview to plot it.
The code which I used to save the result in the file is

```
file=File('grad_shafranov.pvd')
file<<w
```

Comment: Are you restricted to mayavi or could you use vtk as well?

Comment: I am restricted to use mayavi. @Jakob